# how can we get gps data of user's mobile and tablets in our django application?

Tags: django, gps, gpsd

In my django application I need to store the GPS data of all users to track them especially mobile and tablets how can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a table that it stores the locations. Your table schema is like below:

```
Location:

id (auto increment) | user (foreignkey to User) | lat (decimal) | long (decimal) | created_at (datetime)
```

Now you can provide an API that it receives `lat`,`long` and `user`(detect user by token or session) then store these data in the `Location` table.

In the client side, you should get the location from `gps` and send to the API.

Comment: what I meant to say is how to get GPS coordinates (i.e gpsd data) from client devices especially from mobiles how read them using python

Comment: You can not get GPS coordinates by Python. Each mobile device has own OS and you should use the common language for doing it.
For example, Android uses `java` or `kotlin` and IOS `swift` or `objective-c`